# Access alexa's calendar in alexa skill's lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, calendar, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

We want to build a skill that will be invoked by a user every morning.

What we want to do is access the user's calendar in the skill and collect the events.

The events will then trigger another piece of functionality that will send email/sms

Our question is

Can we access alexa user's calendar within our skill's corresponding lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Due to privacy reasons, no access to the user's calendar is provided.

Well, to be accurate, Alexa merely has access details to a user's calendar (rather than having the calendar itself). But that isn't available either.

Skills actually have very little information available. If you want them to connect to some service, you must somehow collect the details from the user. For example, when adding the skill you can **link** the skill to an external resource, which could then ask for further information.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you John. That provides us with the direction that we can link the skill to external resource.